# How to process Facelet and send its output to a String?

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-2.2, myfaces

I'd like to know if there is an API to get the output of a Facelet composition. It is like to call a `<ui:include>` except for getting the output in a String in Java instead of send to a client through HTTP.

I'm using MyFaces.

Comment: I can't ignore the impression that you're looking for the wrong tool for the job. What is it, the actual problem you're trying to solve and for which you [possibly incorrectly thought](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that this all would be the right solution? Are you looking for a templating/view technology for something different than JSF? What exactly then?

Comment: I want to use a template made in jsf to send dynamic e-mails. I can do this manually, but it'll cost more time to develop.

Comment: You're basically looking for a "template engine". Facelets *can* be abused for that, but isn't designed for that, possibly ending up in extra effort to get some specific things to work anyway. I suggest to continue to look around using the [new keywords](http://google.com/search?q=java+template+engine) you was given.

Comment: I bookmarked this question since I do think facelets can be used for this and that it is not neccesarrily abuse (why learn and maintain a separate 'language' if it is not realy needed. I do not have time the coming days but at the end of the week I'll draw up an example that worksfor me.